# Table with multiple TemplateRef in angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I'm using angular 7. I need datatable with two templateRef for my two columns. But my colums coming as empty. What can be the reason? **I added the final version that I want of the painting to the bottom of the page.**

**I can use another things instead of** `ContentChild`

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h9iq1e)

**app.component.html**

```
<app-grid >
  <ng-template let-rowData="rowData" #ColumnStudent>
    Student {{rowData}}
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template let-rowData="rowData" #ColumnTeacher>
    Teacher {{rowData}}
  </ng-template>
</app-grid>


<!--START painting of Final version that I want  -->
<h1 style="color:red">I want table like below in final </h1>

<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th> Students</th>
            <th> Teachers </th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let name of ['Bob','Fred','Gary']">
            <td style='background-color:yellow'>Student {{name}}</td>
            <td style='background-color:lightgreen'>Teacher {{name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<!-- FINISH painting of Final version that I want -->
```

**grid.component.html**

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th> Students</th>
        <th> Teachers </th>
    </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let name of ['Bob','Fred','Gary']">
    <td style='background-color:yellow'><ng-content *ngTemplateOutlet="ColumnStudent; context : {rowData : name}"></ng-content></td>
    <td style='background-color:lightgreen'><ng-content *ngTemplateOutlet="ColumnTeacher; context : {rowData : name}"></ng-content></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**grid.component.ts**

```
export class GridComponent implements OnInit {    
  @ContentChild('ColumnStudent') ColumnStudent: QueryList<ElementRef>;
  @ContentChild('ColumnTeacher') ColumnTeacher: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a local template reference (using #) to the elements inside html that you are referring to using @ContentChild in component.ts

```
<app-grid >
  <ng-template let-rowData="rowData" #ColumnStudent>
    Student {{rowData}}
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template let-rowData="rowData" #ColumnTeacher>
    Teacher {{rowData}}
  </ng-template>
</app-grid>
```

See updated [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d7nzqd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

In your **app.component.ts**, you have missed to create template reference variables. So angular can't detect which **ng-template** you are pointing to, because you have multiple **ng-templates**

```
<app-grid >
  <ng-template #ColumnStudent let-rowData="rowData">
    Student {{rowData}}
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template #ColumnTeacher let-rowData="rowData">
    Teacher {{rowData}}
  </ng-template>
</app-grid>
```

Comment: Thanks @BearNathi.